# How would one calculate the lateral seat force experienced by a roller coaster rider if the turn were banked less than ideal?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, centripetal-force

Given a velocity of 27.8 mi/hr (40.77 ft/sec)around a turn with a radius of 30ft, we can calculate an ideal bank angle of 60 degrees required for the rider to experience 0 lateral G force, and an upward seat force of 2.0+ G. Airplanes, when skillfully flown, make  ordinates turns where the bank angle is properly matched for the radius and velocity - in aviation this is known as coordinating the turn - the coffee in your cup remains level in the cup regardless of how steeply the airplane is banked relative to the horizon. Resolving the two accelerator forces, centripetal and gravity, we can find the resultant.

But roller coaster designers purposely design some turns for a sideways lateral force, which feel like a car rounding a curve too fast. is only banked at 20 degrees but the radius and velocity remain the same the rider will experience a strong lateral g seat force. The bank angle is no longer perpendicular to the resultant of CF and g. How them would we calculate that lateral G seat force? I think I know a way to do this but I’d like to see how a roller coaster designer would calculate it.

Comment: When I when plug in the following values:  r=30’  v=30mph (44 ft/sec) and a bank angle of 20 degrees I get a=59.57 ft/sec^2  .... if I then divide that by g (32ft/sec^2) I end up with 1.86 Gs (lateral I assume). Is that what you get?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Suppose the "bank" is the dark line, the banking angle is $\theta$, the radius of the horizontal circular motion is $r$ and the angular frequency of motion is $\omega=v/r$ where $v$ is the speed. Then there is a centrifugal (horizontal) acceleration of $r\omega^2$ on the rider and a gravitational (vertical) acceleration of $g$.

The components of these two accelerations along the bank are $r\omega^2\cos\theta$ "upwards" and $g\sin
\theta$ "downwards". The resultant acceleration of the rider "upwards" along the bank (the "G-force") is
$$a=r\omega^2\cos\theta -g\sin\theta$$

If the turn is "co-ordinated" then the G-force along the bank is zero (ie $a=0$).
Hence the ideal banking angle $\theta_0$ is given by $$\tan     \theta_0=\frac{r\omega^2}{g}$$

Comment: Yes - that’s how I calculated the”ideal bank angle”  Tbe question goes one step beyond this however. I believe I figured it out since I posted this. The secondary “actual” bank would then be calculated in an identical manner, except the resultant “normal” to the bank plane of the first calculation becomes the “new gravity” (which of course will be higher than 9.8 m/s) and the secondary bank will then be calculated in the same manner as component forces are worked out for an inclined plane relative to the “new horizon” (which is the natural banking plane of the first calculation).

Comment: @CoasterMike Your question asks what is the lateral seat G-force when the "bank" angle is $\theta=20$deg instad of the ideal value $\theta_0$ given by the 2nd equation. The answer is $a$ as given by my 1st equation. All you need to do is insert $\theta=20$deg and values for $r, v, g$ into the 1st equation. You do not need to calculate $\theta_0$ for the ideal "bank" to answer this part of the question..

Comment: I’m still trying to make sense of your answer

Comment: @CoasterMike What don't you understand. Please be specific.

Comment: Wonderful - Figuring it my way I got 1.55Gs - same as I got figuring it your way.  Just had to persevere. Don’t know why your way works but it does. So does my way.